# Include selected language in a href

Tags: routes, navigation, i18n-l10n

I have a few hardcoded links in a block on my homepage.

```
<a href="/info">Info</a>
```

But I want them to include the selected language.

e.g. Wen french is selected I want it to link to

```
<a href="/fr/info">Info<a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [l](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function to print links in Drupal... It has support for language

```
global $language;
print l("Info", "info",  array('language' => $language->language));
```

Comment: Did not use l function, but worked when printing $language->language